# How to drop null elements but not undefined when using `arr.flatMap((f) => f ?? [])`?

Tags: javascript, typescript, null, undefined

I've written a function that removes `null` values from an array:

```js
const dropNull = <T,>(arr: T[]): T[] => {
    return arr.flatMap((f) => f ?? []); // depends >= ES2019
};
```

For example:

```js
const myArr1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', null]
const output1 = dropNull(myArr1) 
console.log(output1) // => ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

However, I realized that it also removes `undefined` values.

```js
const myArr2 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', null, undefined]
const output2 = dropNull(myArr2)
console.log(output2) // => ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Is there a way to just *tweak* the current `dropNull()` in order to remove `null` but not `undefined`? That is, I know I *could have re-written* the function as:

```js
const dropNull2 = <T,>(arr:T[]): T[] => {
    return arr.filter(element => element !== null)
}
```

But I like the `arr.flatMap((f) => f ?? [])` style. Is there a small change to it so it will drop only `null` but not `undefined`?

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgJxABwHIFcA2mYF4YA8AKgDQB8AFAIYIIBcMRA2gLoCUDzLeZMA3gCgAkAgCmUdAjAwaCAHQAzTFSgBZKsgoUFbHjAUwA-IZis2AbhgB6K-FHJRYOBBhl8AUQDKAJgAMARgBOAQBfcwEBUEhYAFsATwBBWn88UwByBRAQNJIYNIAjGhy8woAvYrAsTBZI8GgYEHQoZCaU-EQUDGwKeKSEf11ayBBMUTlMEABzCkbm1t0bPSYAIkyQZdzlwoQNmC2qUuXuCKH63tpvVKYMrOKCotz78tzK7Fz0J1EFAEswUTgalF6rMWlBLu0kGgqj1Ehc2KcRmMJtMQU1vAtbLheCs1rt9jtNmUjjAIkDYLIrmlwKIKlVHlAAO7ZF50vJQAAWYhpLLeMA%20cC%20v3%20LHCp1gYggWCgLnwskU30wUFECAoolGMUcsCx-AEMBgYgkUhgatEGrAsAAhLh8K9MOEQhZSXVYB0odhwYRSJRZHQuBxGKw9IIROJJNI5T9FcrVerNXoTWbLdaYLb4SEncNRuMphRXV1MN4YX10WwgA)

Comment: `return arr.flatMap((f) => f === null ? [] : f);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ternary operators instead

```
return arr.flatMap((f) => f === null ? [] : f);
```